# Jquery Auto Height iframe with the nested iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Hello I have an iframe in my page which have another iframe in it (nested), the nested iframe loads multiple pages of different height currently i am using the code which works for me but only resize the height of the nested one but I want to resize both iframes (the Main iframe and the another iframe which is used in the main one automatically). I searched for the solution but still no success please help me

Here is the code which i am using in both iframe

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';

  }

</script>

<iframe name="Stack" src="inline-main.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' width="1060px">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Put JavaScript in parent page, not inside targeted iframe

I tested your example using the above code in the parent page and the iframed child page, which contains the nested iframe; Both iframes resized as expected.

In your explanation above, you say "Here is the code which i am using in ***both iframe***" *(emphasis added)*, which leads me to think that you have the code inside the targeted iframes, instead of the parent of each targeted iframe.

### Below are the basic contents needed in each page:

---

#### Parent Page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
<iframe src="iframe.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

---

#### Outer iframe

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
<iframe src="nested-iframe.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

---

#### Nested iframe

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

---

**NOTE:** You can only do this on iframes from the *same domain*. It will not work on cross-domain iframes. Also, if you have access to all of the pages including the parent page, then I wouldn't suggest using iframes for the loading of same-domain content; use AJAX or, if available, a jQuery AJAX-based method [`.ajax()`, `.get()`, `.load()`] instead.